# Alternating x-Axis plotbands with highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my highstock chart I want to display an alternating vertical background, where the background from the first to the second major tick is white, from the second to the third it is lightgray, then white again, then lightgray again. You get the idea.

[image: Example for alternating backgrounds]

The trick is, that this should dynamically update on zooming. When I zoom in on the navigator, so that the ticks change e.g. from one per month to one per week, the background should still alternate on each major tick.

I assume, that `xAxis.plotBands` is the way to go, but I didn't see any option to attach them to ticks instead of specific dates.

Can anyone point me please to the correct option?

If there is no option which could do this: How could I simulate this then? Write some javascript-function called everytime the navigator selection changes, reading the current positions of the major ticks, removing all current plotbands then adding new plotbands where needed?

Comment: Check the docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.alternateGridColor

Comment: @jlbriggs I *just* found this option myself. I simply looked at the wrong options. Make it an answer, I'll accept it and let's call it a day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve with a built-in option for the axes, `alertnateGridColor`

You provide the color, it automatically fills an alternating area between the major ticks.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.alternateGridColor